# Diagnostics and statistics for messages in aplication with Apache Camel and Active MQ

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, apache-camel

In my disturbed java application I use Apache Camel and Active MQ for comminication between nodes. I want to store same data about queues in Active MQ. I want to make a statictics and automatically detect is a queue is not getting overload. I could not find any tools that Apache Camel and Active MQ provide to do such things. Do you know any? Or Maybe I just missed something in documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In ActiveMQ you have a choice of a number of mechanisms:

- [JMX](http://activemq.apache.org/jmx.html) - also accessible through [REST/JSON via Jolokia](http://activemq.apache.org/rest.html), which is available by default from 5.8 and accessible on your system at `http://localhost:8161/api/jolokia/`
- [statistics plugin](http://activemq.apache.org/statisticsplugin.html) for polling/querying via JMS
- [advisory messages](http://activemq.apache.org/advisory-message.html) to have interesting broker events pushed to you via JMS

Answer (score 2):

There is also hawtio which is a HTML5 based web console for managing java stuff and has plugins for both Camel and ActiveMQ: http://hawt.io/

In the ActiveMQ 5.9 release the old web-console will be replaced with hawtio. And over time additionally functionally for ActiveMQ is being added to the ActiveMQ plugin.

Also if you use a Karaf based system, then there is karaf commands for ActiveMQ, which you can use to get queue stats etc.